# How to improve fitness and turnover in websim?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

Well, I am new to quantitative finance.After reading a few things I started developing alphas on the websim platform by worldquant.Almost all the alphas I made had a decent sharpe(>2), but they actually lagged behind in fitness(>1/>1.3 depending upon the delay) & turnover(<70% as per worldquant standards).

I have been told that increasing the decay decreases the turnover,but from my observation it also seems to mess up with the fitness of the alpha.

Can someone suggest me some ways to improve on these parameters?